# Qual a forma correta de chamar um método de uma classe que herda de uma activity?

Tags: android, android-activity

Porque se eu instanciar a classe com o "new" e chamar o método igual ao Java não funciona. Tenho uma classe que herda de uma activity e eu precisava usar o método dela em várias classes. Alguém sabe como fazer isso? Agradeço desde já.

Comment: Você precisa dar uma estuda melhor no ciclo de vida do Android e principalmente em design patterns, com isso você ira encontrar as respostas para as suas perguntas, mas já adiantando uma das soluções é você utilizar o padrão Singleton.

Answer (score 2):

Nenhuma classe que herde de *Activity* deve/pode ser instanciada com "new".

> Uma *Activity* é um componente de aplicação que fornece uma tela com a qual os usuários podem interagir, a fim de fazer alguma coisa.[[Ler mais]](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html)

Elas são geridas internamente pelo *Android Activity framework* que, entre outras coisas, gere o seu ciclo de vida. Por isso ela terá de ser criada recorrendo ao mecanismo que o *framework* disponibiliza para isso.

Uma *Activity* terá de ser lançada recorrendo a um [Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) que descreve a *Activity* que você deseja iniciar. O Intent especifica a *Activity* que você deseja iniciar ou descreve o tipo de acção que você deseja executar.

Se uma *Activity* necessita de aceder a métodos de outra *Activity* então a sua aplicação está mal estruturada.

Existem várias formas de evitar essa necessidade.
Elas dependerão do que você pretender fazer, por isso terá de ser mais especifico na sua pergunta.

Comment: Eu estou usando um método para verificar se há conexão no meu dispositivo, para isso eu preciso usar uma activity. Como vou usar este método 5 vezes, não queria ter que replicar o código.

Comment: Por que esse método tem de estar numa Activity?

Answer (score 2):

Você pode criar uma classe Utils, por exemplo. Nessa classe você cria um método para verificar a conexão. Provavelmente você precisará de um objeto Context para fazer a verificação. Você poderá receber o Context como parâmetro do método. Por exemplo:

```
public static boolean checkConnection(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager cm =
        (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting();
}
```

Nas suas activities você pode chamar:

```
Utils.checkConnection(this)
```

Parte desse código foi extraída dessa resposta [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560788/how-to-check-internet-access-on-android-inetaddress-never-timeouts)